# jQuery Alert if paragraph is selected and has specific class

Tags: jquery, html

I have html code like below.

```
<div id='p1' class='thread'>
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Abbot and Costello - Africa Screams</p>
</div>

<div id='p2' class='thread selected'>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p class='flag'>Abbot and Costello - Frank/Meet</p>
</div>

<div id='p3' class='thread'>
<p>Third Paragraph</p>
<p>addin</p>
</div>

<div id='p4' class='thread'>
<p>Forth Paragraph</p>
<p>Begins</p>
</div>
```

Every time user clicks on paragraph new class "selected" is added and previous one is removed.

I want to `alert('flag');` if a `<div>` has class `selected` and `<p>` has class `flag` like in Second Paragraph.

how can I achieve this using "jQuery".

any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `click` handler you need to check if the clicked `div.thread` has `selected` class and test if it contains a paragraph with `class="flag"` using `.find('p.flag')`.

This is how should be your code:

```
$('div.thread').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("selected") && $(this).find('p.flag')) {
    alert('flag');
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('div.thread').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("selected") && $(this).find('p.flag')) {
    alert('flag');
  }
});
```

```css
.selected{
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='p1' class='thread'>
  <p>First Paragraph</p>
  <p>Abbot and Costello - Africa Screams</p>
</div>

<div id='p2' class='thread selected'>
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
  <p class='flag'>Abbot and Costello - Frank/Meet</p>
</div>

<div id='p3' class='thread'>
  <p>Third Paragraph</p>
  <p>addin</p>
</div>

<div id='p4' class='thread'>
  <p>Forth Paragraph</p>
  <p>Begins</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEGLqX

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).find('p').hasClass('flag')) {
    alert('flag');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("p").click(function(){
if($(this).attr('class') == 'flag) { 
alert('flag');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("flag")){
        if($(this).parent().hasClass("selected")){
            alert("flag");
        }
            else{}
        }
    else{}
    });
});   
        </script>
```